# How to re-prompt for user input in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a simple prompt for user input as the following:

```
Is this correct? (Y/N):
```

This prompt should only take either a `Y` or a `N` and should re-prompt the user if any other input has been entered.

Could someone please show me a snippet of code on how this can be done? I am still very new with Tcl.

Comment: `while {[puts -nonewline {Is this correct (Y/N)};set input [gets stdin]] ni {Y N}} {}`

Comment: Hmm, four (well, five) ways to do it, all of which are slightly different. If you want to get a better answer, constrain things a little more…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very hard to do well. The key is to remember to `flush` after printing the prompt, to check for end-of-file (using a negative result and call to `eof`) and do something to stop if that happens, and to use `-strict` with your `string is` calls.

```
proc promptForBoolean {prompt} {
    while 1 {
        puts -nonewline "${prompt}? (Yes/No) "
        flush stdout;    # <<<<<<<< IMPORTANT!
        if {[gets stdin line] < 0 && [eof stdin]} {
            return -code error "end of file detected"
        } elseif {[string is true -strict [string tolower $line]]} {
            return 1
        } elseif {[string is false -strict [string tolower $line]]} {
            return 0
        }
        puts "Please respond with yes or no"
    }
}

set correct [promptForBoolean "Is this correct"]
puts "things are [expr {$correct ? {good} : {bad}}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can the following snippet: get data from stdin (standard input) until you find something valid.

```
puts "Is this correct? (Y/N)"

set data ""
set valid 0 
while {!$valid} {
    gets stdin data
    set valid [expr {($data == Y) || ($data == N)}]
    if {!$valid} {
        puts "Choose either Y or N"
    }
}

if {$data == Y} {
    puts "YES!"
} elseif {$data == N} {
    puts "NO!"
}
```

Comment: Why easy if there is a complicated way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. It accepts `y`, `yes`, `n` and `no` case insensitively.

```
proc yesNoPrompt {question} {
  while {1} {
    puts -nonewline stderr "$question (Y/N): "
    if {[gets stdin line] < 0} {
      return -1
    }
    switch -nocase -- $line {
      n - no {
        return 0
      }
      y - yes {
        return 1
      }
    }
  }
}

yesNoPrompt "Is this correct?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will accept y, yes, true, 1, n, no, false...

```
proc isCorrect {} {
   set input {}
   while {![string is boolean -strict $input]} {
       puts -nonewline {Is this correct (Y/N)}
       flush stdout
       set input [gets stdin]
   }
   return [string is true -strict $input]
}
if {[isCorrect]} {
   puts "Correct"
} else {
   puts "not correct"
}
```

Comment: The official list of boolean values is documented (http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/GetInt.htm#M5)